# Rename files to grandfather folder name

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

So I have a bunch of folders with similar directories to the below:

```
.\page\1\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png
.\page\2\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png
.\page\3\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png
```

I want to rename all the .png files the number just before the first randomStringofCharacters. So basically:

```
.\page\1\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png -> 1.png
.\page\2\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png -> 2.png
.\page\3\randomStringofCharacters\randomStringofCharactersAgain.png -> 3.png
```

Is there any batch script that can do this? I have tried:

```
@Echo OFF

FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
    FOR %%@ in ("*.png") DO (
        Echo Ren: ".\%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
        Ren "%%@" "%%~n#%%~x@"
    )
    POPD
)

Pause&Exit
```

Yet this only renames the file with the parent directory. And if possible is there a way to move all such renamed .png files in to a newly made folder in `.\page\` (the same place where the .bat is) with the folder name of page?

Thanks in advanced! (I haven't touched .bat in probably around 10 years, so please if possible explain what you've done, so I can learn therefrom)

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but generally, to access the "grandfather" you need to add one another period. That it, I guess it should be `Echo Ren: "..\%% and so on`. Regarding your second question ("And if possible...") - you should understand that Superuser is not a "please, do my work for me" community. You cannot simply give us a task and expect we will try to solve it.

Comment: You want to move the files to `.\page\page`, right?  Go with **Powershell** (openned to  `.\page`). Copy & paste this code :   `md page | out-null ; gci *.png -s | %{ $_ | move-item -Destination { 'page\{0}.png' -f $_.FullName.Split('\')[-3] }}`

Comment: Assuming the batch file is on the desktop would the expected result be .\page\desktop\1.png  .\page\desktop\2.png  .\page\desktop\3.png ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got this part right "And if possible is there a way to move all such renamed .png files in to a newly made folder in .\page\ (the same place where the .bat is) with the folder name of page?"

Would it be something like this?

[image]

```
@echo off

if exist "%~1" (IF not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)
if /i not exist "%~dp0Page" md "%~dp0Page"

pushd "%~1"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b *.png') do Call :Rename "%%~a" "%%~dpa"
exit

:Rename
set Cpath=%~2
set Cpath=%Cpath:~0,-1%
For %%a in ("%Cpath%") do set Cpath=%%~dpa
set Cpath=%Cpath:~0,-1%
for %%a in ("%Cpath%") do set NName=%%~nxa
move "%~1" "%~dp0Page\%NName%%~x1"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thankyou very much!